# Spring boot Unique index or primary key violation when using jwt to authenticate, when multiple authentication requests in a short time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am using jwt to authenticate in my spring boot app. These are methods in AuthenticationService:

```java
public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword()
                )
        );
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail()).orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);
        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        String refreshToken = jwtService.generateRefreshToken(user);
        revokeAllUserTokens(user);
        saveUserToken(user, jwtToken);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .accessToken(jwtToken)
                .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                .build();
    }

private void revokeAllUserTokens(User user) {
        List<Token> validUserTokens = tokenRepository.findAllValidTokenByUser(user.getId());
        if(validUserTokens.isEmpty())
            return;
        validUserTokens.forEach(token -> {
            token.setExpired(true);
            token.setRevoked(true);
        });
        tokenRepository.saveAll(validUserTokens);
    }

private void saveUserToken(User user, String jwtToken) {
        Token token = Token.builder()
                .user(user)
                .token(jwtToken)
                .tokenType(TokenType.BEARER)
                .expired(false)
                .revoked(false)
                .build();
        tokenRepository.save(token);
    }
```

and in JwtService:

```java
public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails) {
        return buildToken(extraClaims, userDetails, jwtConfig.getExpiration());
    }

    public String generateRefreshToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return buildToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails, jwtConfig.getRefreshTokenExpiration());
    }
```

and Token inside database:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "jwt_tokens")
public class Token {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "token", unique = true)
    public String token;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public TokenType tokenType = TokenType.BEARER;

    public boolean revoked;
    public boolean expired;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public User user;

}
```

rest of the implementation is rather self explanatory.

It works fine, but when there are multiple authentication request (when I rapidly send multiple requests), there is 500 status response, and an exception is thrown (method authenticate in AuthenticationService) is called:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.CONSTRAINT_INDEX_4 ON PUBLIC.JWT_TOKENS(TOKEN NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 7 */ 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtYWx5enNAZW1haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjkwMjE4NDU3LCJleHAiOjE2OTAzMDQ4NTd9.8aePz6jl3JPvsnDFVpXxtzYfsxLN0ZqIUg0FsK_XDaE' )"; SQL statement:
insert into jwt_tokens (expired,revoked,token,token_type,user_id,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?) [23505-214]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT tokens, by design, use UNIX Epoch time in seconds for `iat` (issued at) time.

I reckon a good hack would be to include additional information in `extraClaims` when generating JWT tokens, for example the current time in miliseconds. This doesn't change the usage of tokens as they still get hashed.

In terms of your implementation, a possible change would be:

```
String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(Map.of("milis", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())), user);
String refreshToken = jwtService.generateRefreshToken(Map.of("milis", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())), user);
```